# Making a duplicate of a path in Unix

Tags: linux, directory, filenames

My Unix vocabulary is failing me.  I have 5 billion images in `/foo/live/images`.

For the purposes of developing a new version of the app I'd like to make `/foo/dev/images` into a working path without making a copy of the images.

Is this a soft link?  What's the right term?  What's the command-line syntax to create the link?

Answer (score 9):

Dead simple, it's just a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /foo/live/images /foo/dev/images
```

Just watch the directory permissions etc. To view the man page (all available options) for the `ln` command, enter the following at the prompt:

```
man ln
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use either symbolic links or hard links (for individual files) assuming they are on the same filesystem.

```
cd /foo/live; find images -type d -printf "mkdir -vp '/foo/dev/%p'\n" -o -type f -printf "ln -vs '/foo/live/%p' '/foo/dev/%p'\n" | sh
```

From http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1776/create-a-symbolic-link-tree-that-shadows-a-directory-structure

Whether you do this or `cd /foo/dev; ln -s ../live/images .` depends on whether you might write into the images directory.

Comment: Hard links for "5 billion images" - really? Whilst you're answer is correct, I'd opt for a more canonical example for a *nix novice.

Comment: @Mikaveli: Sure, you are using a lot of inodes (symlinks) and directory entries/inodes (both), but for some applications/usage patterns you might not be able to use the directory symlink.  We didn't get enough information to say which was needed so I provided the option.